# What is the correct way to specify a field for a data type that may not have a value

Tags: haskell, types, option-type

I would like to specify a custom data type as follows:

```
data Colour = Red | Green | Blue deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
data Geometry = Star | Square deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
data Shape = Shp {colour :: Colour, geom :: Geometry} deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

now, what if I do not require to have the colour always specified. Is this the right way?

```
data Shape = Shp {colour :: Maybe Colour, geom :: Geometry} deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

Is this thew way this should be done in Haskell? Are there any alternatives, and drawbacks of this? So far, stuff compiles, but I am at the begining of the learning curve and have found only one place where this has been used, without any manifestation how follow-up functions deal with this situation.

For instance, accessing the value through colour(s) and so on, as well as the Show function then end up with a lot of "Just Red" etc.

Comment: yes this is the usual way - an alternative (thats really the same) would be do define `data Shape = Colored Color Geometry | UnColored Geometry` - but stick with this! If the `Just color` really bothers you , I would drop the `Maybe` and just set a default-color in the undecided cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I almost just wrote the one word response "Yes" and clicked submit.  What you wrote is absolutely correct.

As with most languages, there are many other ways to do this, but this really is the "idiomatic" way (you will have to learn this word to communicate with the Haskell crowd :) ).  For instance, a second inferior way would be to extend Colour to include `NoColour`....  But this is not a clean datatype then, and the resulting type is less reusable (ie- a type with just colours can easily be extended using Maybe, but a type with `NoColour` can't be unextended if you need that).

One word of warning though:

If you use wrap something in `Maybe`, `Either`, etc, you will find that your code becomes complicated in the short term, because even simple functions will need to account for the `Just` and `Nothing` cases, as well as your colours.  Often you might start to have a staircase of statements just to deal with the cases....  Fixing this is when you will really start to learn about Haskell (monads, etc), and then your code will quickly start to excel.

(I can't believe you got me to spell colour like that for a whole post :) ).

Comment: Thanks for spelling Colour my way :). What prompted me to ask was exactly this staircase of complicated ways of dealing with the Justs, and often this causes me problems. For instance, if I have a record notation based data type which accesses a field that can be a Just xy, that may have additional Just fields... I have no idea how to deal with this elegantly. I am also trying to avoid Monads, as my system is very small, minimal and assuming a constant setup ( it is really  just a formal system to proof something is mathematically correct ins some sense). So all inputs are hardcoded variables

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @carsten-könig's answer, using GADTs it is possible to statically ensure that some functions will only ever be used when the colour is statically known to be there whilst others can be defined generically over all shapes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Shapes where

data Colour = Red | Green | Blue deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
data Geometry = Star | Square deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

We introduce two types whose constructors we don't care about but which are *distinguished* by Haskell.

```
data Filled
data Blank
```

We now add a type parameter to `Shape`. Depending whether a `Colour` has been assigned to the shape or not, the return type of our `Shape` constructors will be different.

```
data Shape a where
  Coloured   :: Colour -> Geometry -> Shape Filled
  UnColoured :: Geometry           -> Shape Blank
```

We can now write functions which are colour-preserving such as transforming a `Shape` into a square:

```
toSquare :: Shape a -> Shape a
toSquare (Coloured col _) = Coloured col Square
toSquare (UnColoured _)   = UnColoured Square
```

Or we may define a function only on the subset for which it makes sense to have this operation: `safeSetColour` is the function refusing to overwrite a previously assigned colour whilst `getColour` is the function only working on `Shape`s which *do* have a Colour and extracts it.

```
safeSetColour :: Shape Blank -> Colour -> Shape Filled
safeSetColour (UnColoured g) col = Coloured col g

getColour :: Shape Filled -> Colour
getColour (Coloured col _) = col
```

Now, the `Either` monad only ever creeps in when you need to ensure statically that a Shape is either `Filled` or `Blank`:

```
decide :: Shape a -> Either (Shape Filled) (Shape Blank)
decide s@(Coloured _ _) = Left s
decide s@(UnColoured _) = Right s
```